# Form elements update and deletion in D7

Tags: 7, forms

I have made a form in D7 using form API,submitted values to that and retrieved entries from database;now what i want is to add a delete link in front of every retrieved row.My retrieval code is:

```
function form_data_menu() {
$items['formdata'] = array(
'title' => 'Form Data',
'page callback' => 'form_data_form',
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function form_data_form()
{
 $results = db_query('SELECT * FROM {drupal}');
 $header = array(t('Id'),t('Name'),t('College'),t('Education'),t('Percentage'),t('Application'));
$rows = array();
foreach($results as $result){
$rows[] = array(
$result->id,
 $result->name,
 $result->college,
 $result->education,
$result->percentage,
 $result->application,
);
}
return theme('table',array('header'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));
}
```

any help will be appreciated. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it in addition to this code. You need to create another url to delete a record from the database

```
$items['deldata'] = array(
'title' => 'Delete data',
'page callback' => 'form_delete_form',
'page arguments' =>array(1),
'access callback' => TRUE,
);

function form_delete_form($arg){
$query = db_query("delete * from the 'table_name' where 'id' =$arg");
drupal_set_message("Record deleted successfully.");
drupal_goto('formdata');

}

function form_data_form()
{
  global $base_url;
 $results = db_query('SELECT * FROM {drupal}');
 $header = array(t('Id'),t('Name'),t('College'),t('Education'),t('Percentage'),t('Application'), t('Options'));
$rows = array();
foreach($results as $result){
$rows[] = array(
$result->id,
 $result->name,
 $result->college,
 $result->education,
$result->percentage,
 $result->application,
'<a href='.$base_url.'/deldata/'.$result->id.'>Delete</a>', 
);
}
return theme('table',array('header'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));
}
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks @TBI Infotech...but it didn't work...i'm still getting the same data which i was getting earlier on retrieval (from database)...can you please point me towards some nice tutorials?